# Error when get data using regex in php

Tags: php

I have an string:

```
$text =array();
$text[0] = "Microsoft Windows Phone 7.5 Mango";
$text[1] = "Microsoft Windows Phone 7";


for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){
    preg_match_all('/(Microsoft Windows)<\/i>\s*(.*)/', $text[$i], $value) ;
    print_r($value);
}
```

When i print_r($value) is result is array() array(), how to fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `<\/i>` that's a closing HTML tag that does not appear in the input strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as @Sarke mentioned and remove the `<\/i>`.  But if this code might have to parse strings that contain this tag, then make your expression ignore it:

```
preg_match_all('/(Microsoft Windows)(<\/i>)?\s*(.*)/', $text[$i], $value) ;
```

Also, I would recommend instead of hard-coding the length of your array, use `count()`, like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($text); $i++) {
```

This way your code is more future-proof if/when the number of items in your `$text` array changes.

Comment: Might as well use foreach($text as $t) instead.